# firebase json db security rule using fb authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 angular for my mobile app and fb native cordova plugin is used to login.

The firebase db security documentation uses the syntax like

```
{  
   "rules":{  
      "users":{  
         "$user_id":{  
            ".write":"$user_id === auth.id"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

the fb authentication looks like below in my app

```
 doLogin(){
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      return this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
         firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
         this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage); 
      })
    }
}
```

my question is the auth firebase variable is taken care with above code or i need to something extra for auth to get required uid etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

The auth firebase variable is token care of in theory: assuming you have the *Facebook sign-in method* enabled already. However, the *database* rules you are showing are not necessarily related.

These rules (the same as above):

```
"rules": {
    "users":{
        "$variable":{ ".write": "$variable=== auth.uid" }
```

Dictate that users can only write to a child node with the same uid. I changed `$user_id` to `$variable` to highlight that the `$` simply denotes a variable that represents the child node's name.
(I should probably mention that it should be `auth.uid` not `auth.id`)

This is used to save user specific data. So, when they signup you could have a function that says

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update(<your custom data here>);
```

*please note how the child of users is the "firebase.auth().currentUser.uid" which can optionally be retrieved from the `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential()` promise.

Sorry if the explanation was more that necessary. In short. the uid is always present with `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` after login and that uid is what the database rules are referring to in `auth.uid` and last, the auth/uid/etc is pretty much 100% taken care of with firebase.

Comment: yes main intention was to ask if its taken care. i didnt pay too much attention of exact rule definitions